# Hard time on understanding real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, paradoxes

I am learning real analysis now but I really dislike the notion of limit, infinity... They seems to generate lots of paradoxes and unreasonable results.

For example, when I am reading the uniform continuous notion, there is an example I find quite annoying to accept:
Consider the sequence of function: (check the pictures below, I am new so I don't know how to insert math notations, and they wont allow me to display images)
[definition of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGG0Y.png)
[reason why its pointwise convergent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkBcD.png)

see its really feels like a fallacy to say that in one place that for every $x$, you can find a $k$ large enough to do blabla, and in another place to say that for every $k$, you can find a $x$ that is large enough to do the opposite thing.

I know its logically right, but I don't think this is the future of mathematics. There is too many procedures and actions, if an alien is learning our notions of math he may not be satisfied I guess.

Thanks for any help and insightful thoughts.

Comment: StackExchange has LateX support. Just use the dollar sign, type an equation, close with the dollar sign.

Comment: I believe that mathematics is like a sinous curve. You are the mathematician, and you are accumulating stuffs and baggaages on your car. Although the curve be extremely sinuous, your car will not drop out your baggage, it is all well hold.

Comment: Learning mathematics can take a long time.  Keep at it.  Talk to your instructors.  Talk to other mathematics students.  Perhaps you will learn to like it.  Or perhaps you will find out that you are better suited for opera singing or auto mechanics.

Comment: So is there any real question here or is it just a random ranting?

Comment: You say "its really feels like a fallacy" and you also say "I know its logically right". Surely this just indicates a problem with your feelings, not a problem with the math! Too many procedures and actions, not satisfying? So what? "Not satisfed" is not a fallacy.

Comment: My point is in the definition of limits, or pointwise convergence, there are many words such as "given", "fixed", like in the previous example, if I make x fixed, and give a number greater than zero, then I can find N such as... But x's range is whole real number field, if I lose this "fix" or focus, then the condition will not hold. Just like Hilbert's paradox of the Grand Hotel, if you loose the focus, then every room is full, but if you focus on specific room, then it can be accommodated.

Comment: this sense of objective action and outside operator in math makes it less "pure" and convincing in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Real analysis is hard. It took mathematicians centuries to figure out careful correct logical ways to describe things like the difference between continuity and uniform continuity, in order to avoid the things that look like paradoxes to you.

I think this really is both the present and the future of mathematics. If you find it alien even after struggling to understand it then perhaps you should find something else to study that pleases you more.